# How do you convert a SOAP PolylineN from one namespace to another?

Tags: arcgis-server, c#, arcgis-web-adf, arcgis-soap-api

I'm doing a proof-of-concept to try to speed up a data service that accesses DB2 databases and a GeometryService on an ArcGIS server using the ADF and the SOAP API. I'm trying to speed up data access by getting features using a feature service.

The problem I'm running into is that ArcGIS Server's ADF doesn't seem to be able to convert its own data types. 
I have a PolylineN value object from a FeatureService that I need to convert to the same class for a GeometryService.

The documentation online says to use .NET XML serialization, but the examples only convert a service's value object to an ADF value object, not from ADF to a service's value object or one service to another.

Converting from one service's PolylineN to the other doesn't work. I tried a two-step process, converting from FeatureService.PolylineN to ADF.PolyLineN, then from ADF.PolylineN to GeometryService.PolylineN. On deserializing to GeometryService.PolylineN, I get this error:

System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (9, 10).
The Inner Exception is the same type, with the message: "The specified type was not recognized: name='PointN', namespace='http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.0', at ."

According to the documentation, PolylineN is essentially identical in all of these namespaces. So why can't they understand each other's schema?

My workaround is to build a new GeometryService.PolylineN from the feature polyline. It works, but it seems unnecessary to me.

Does anybody have any hints on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using multiple services via SOAP, creating shared value objects is recommended and much more convenient than converting to Web ADF/ArcOBjects geometric objects.

See this page for how to achieve this:

http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/soap/Using_multiple_services_in_a_single_application.htm

Comment: I must have searched a dozen times and missed that one. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: The SOAP API documentation is severely limited. IMHO, it is  much more powerful than the REST endpoint, but unfortunately it is hardly used.Even I had to break my head over this for couple of days before I found this link. I'm glad that it helped you out.